# Send an Error Message by E-Mail php

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to get a mail if any error occurs in my php apps. I found an example on https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp:

```
<?php
    //error handler function
function customError($errno, $errstr) {
  echo "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr<br>";
  echo "Webmaster has been notified";
  error_log("Error: [$errno] $errstr",1,
  "uwe.nachname@gmail.com","From: webmaster@example.com");
}
//set error handler
set_error_handler("customError",E_USER_WARNING);
//trigger error
$test=2;
if ($test>=1) {
  trigger_error("Value must be 1 or below",E_USER_WARNING);
}
?>
```

This is working, but when I change it for all errors not:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
//error handler function
function customError($errno, $errstr) {
  echo "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr<br>";
  echo "Webmaster has been notified";
  error_log("Error: [$errno] $errstr",1,
  "uwe.nachname@gmail.com","From: webmaster@example.com");
}
//set error handler
set_error_handler("customError",E_ALL);
  echo 'now the error: ';
  echo gibtsnicht();
?>
```

What can I do to get a mail for any error??
Thanks and greetings from Austria
Uwe

Comment: Kind of unrelated but I spotted a minor issue with your code. `if ($test>=1) {trigger_error("Value must be 1 or below",E_USER_WARNING);}` is still going to trigger if `$test` is 1 which contradicts your message

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this is not triggering an error, but an exception, so the exception has to be caught and handled.

```
<?php
function customException($ex) {
  echo "<b>Exception:</b> ".$ex->getMessage()." Line: ".$ex->getLine() ."<br>";
  error_log("Exception: " .$ex->getMessage()." File: ".$ex->getFile()." Line: ".$ex->getLine(),1,
  "uwe.nachname@gmail.com","From: webmaster@example.com");
  echo "Webmaster has been notified";
}

set_exception_handler("customException"); 
  echo 'now the exception: <br>';
  echo gibtsnicht();
?>
```

Check out [Exception](http://php.net/manual/de/class.exception.php)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a PHP beginner and transferring my app from ASP to PHP because I am 69...

Comment: Just one question: How can I send the programmname and the linenummer too?